# Meteor Form getting input value with dynamic name

Tags: javascript, meteor

Taking this form from meteor tutorial as example

```
<form>
        <input type="text" name="playerName">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Player">
</form>
```

I am able to use **event.target.playerName.value** to access the value of the input.
However if my input name is generated dynamically, how do I access it?

eg. I have playerName1, playerName2, playerName3 and I want to use a for loop to access them.

```
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        console.log(event.target.playerName+i.value)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to object variables using the array notation as well, for example

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    console.log(event.target[playerName+i].value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was looking for